# signed url upload from golang: SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

when I pass the signed URL returned from a POST to upload to a file, there's seems to be an encoding (or decoding ?) of the URL inside this function http.NewRequest:

```
req, err = http.NewRequest(http.MethodPut, uploadResp.UploadURL, bytes.NewBuffer(json))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

here's uploadResp.UploadURL, which BTW I can use to upload the file successfully via curl.

```
... .s3.amazonaws.com/test?AWSAccessKeyId=...&Signature=RDCEz7QLLtVPhUynLR69%2BzR9POc%3D&x-amz-security-token=...
```

but when I run the golang code, here's what I got:

```
...The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
<SignatureProvided>RDCEz7QLLtVPhUynLR69+zR9POc=</SignatureProvided>
```

is there a way to prevent http.NewRequest to do any transformation in the URL? 
maybe work on the server side:

```
put_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        'put_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': bucketName,
            'Key': 'test', 
        },
        ExpiresIn=300,
        HttpMethod='PUT'
    )
```

thanks

Comment: ok, I was shooting myself in the foot with the req.Header.Set( ..json charset=utf-8) line, removed that and boom!